# Custom post types loop on a page template

Tags: wp-query, query, pre-get-posts

Hi I'm trying to make a page template that shows a list of a custom post type ordered by a meta key, I easily made it with `query_posts` but I am trying to do it via `pre_get_posts` so I made a function like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'events');
function events($query) {
  if ( is_page_template('page-myevents.php') ){
    $query->set('post_type', 'events');
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'start' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );        
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    $query->set('numberposts', 5); 
  }
}
```

But it does not work when i enter the page it sends me to the 404 page, I even added `$query->get_posts()` but nothing I get errors with that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible. Why do you need a page template? Why can't you use a custom post type archive, which is built-in to WordPress ( if you register the post type with `has_archive` set to true).  I'm ignoring all your other possible $args, because I don't know how you are registering this post type.

```
register_post_type( 'events', array( 'has_archive' => true ) );
```

Then you can just adjust the query to order by the meta

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'events');
function events($query) {
  if ( is_post_type_archive('events' ) ){
    add_query_var( 'meta_key', 'start' );
    add_query_var( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );        
    add_query_var( 'order', 'DESC' );
    add_query_var('numberposts', 5); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The thing is I want to make a list of posts that the user can edit, not necessary posts that are assigned to the user. It can be done using a meta_query which was very easy to do with WP_Query but when I tried with pre_get_posts I get a 404 error. Could probably change the author archive in case this is not possible.

Comment: @TolucaCulturalInvitación - you get a 404 error because WordPress is trying to load the requested pagename from your events post type. You can't reliably convert a query for a page into a different sort of query via `pre_get_posts`, you need to do a separate query via `WP_Query`.

Comment: @TolucaCulturalInvitación Ah ok. Didn't know you were trying to something other than list the posts. @Milo confirmed what I suspected about converting the query, so unless you can explain that part more clearly, I too would suggest `WP_Query`

Comment: So if there is no way to convert a query, is there a way of not running the query? The case is, I don't really need the page contents so there is no point on making that query.